# Is it ok to use convicted as an adjective in this sense?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

The word "convicted" is generally used as the following:

> "A convicted criminal"

> "He was convicted"

However, I wanted to show that someone did something with conviction, in a form like this:

> "He did so with convicted purpose."

Is this usage incorrect?

Comment: I've never heard it.  With 'with convicted purpose' would normally be expressed as *with conviction*.

Comment: Apparently, adverbial ***convictedly** = **with conviction*** suddenly [shot to prominence if the 1880s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=convictedly&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), but has been tailing off ever since. I suggest non-native speakers in particular (or basically, *anyone* who's so unsure of their vocabulary that they might seek such advice here) should avoid that single-word form today in favour of the preposition-based two-word alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The OED sense 5 of the verb ***to convict*** relates to religious conviction. There are no more recent examples than from the seventeenth century.

Although the OED declares the sense *obsolete*, I can claim to have heard it used by an evangelical Christian to describe someone's realisation of spiritual prompting in the form 'he was suddenly convicted'.

But it is a very outdated mode of speech even among profound evamgelicals I suspect.

> 5. To compel (a person) by proof, argument, etc. to acknowledge an assertion, confess an opinion, etc.; = convince v. 3. Obsolete.
>
> 1583   A. Golding tr. J. Calvin Serm. on Deuteronomie vii. 39   The
> people were conuicted of Gods mighty working in their behalfe.
>
> 1598   R. Grenewey tr. Tacitus Annales i. iv. 7   [He would] by his
> owne confession conuict him, that the Common-wealth was but one bodie.
>
> 1646   Sir T. Browne Pseudodoxia Epidemica i. i. 3   He did not
> indubitably believe, untill he was after convicted in the visible
> example of Abel. View more context for this quotation
>
> 1659   M. Casaubon in J. Dee True & Faithful Relation Spirits Pref.
> sig. D1v   If by that time he be not convicted, he shall have my good
> will to give it over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this usage in the dictionaries I've checked, and I don't remember ever seeing it. However, I'm sorry to report:

> We make emotional investments of time, effort, care. They pay us back
> in that we gain **convicted purpose**, self-definition, inner momentum,
> and self respect. When we lose interpersonal connections, we forfeit
> this source of a sense of purpose. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clinical_Values/0oBmXeiUHEoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22convicted%20purpose%22&pg=PT126&printsec=frontcover)

> Months of sheer agony, remaining persistent with **convicted determination**, and never giving up on our love. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Loving_A_Narcissist/Kj3XAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22convicted%20determination%22&pg=PA206&printsec=frontcover)

> They were dressed in civilian clothing and infiltrated the protesters,
> once again exhibiting a **convicted determination** which had not been
> seen on the Iranian political scene since the riots preceding the 1979
> revolution. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Understanding_Shiite_Leadership/3HCFAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22convicted%20determination%22&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover)

> ESPRESSO YOURSELF (SAY WHAT YOU THINK)
> An inspired and deeply
> **convicted attitude** toward sharing one's insight or perspective on topics that are personally and professionally relevant; [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Leading_Clarity/uoxODwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22convicted%20attitude%22&pg=PA121&printsec=frontcover)

I think we know all we need to about using *convicted* in this sense when we see it just after *espresso* as a verb (colors are being discussed, and I get the pun, still...)

I am not convicted this usage is proper.

Comment: Not all dictionaries list "convicted" as an adjective (Merriam-Webster doesn't, Lexico does) but even if it's used in one sense as an adjective, that doesn't preclude using the past participle form in the way you'd use a past participle (which overlaps with when you use an adjective, including before a noun).

Comment: I agree, which is why I did a search for it with some nouns that might follow logically to see if was indeed used this way.